# How to save each data from an array to the database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

[image: array of data]

I have a form where I needed to split into two table in the database. `tbl_1` consist of single value per column, then `tbl_2` consist of multiple value per column. I know if I pass multiple data per column I'm going to violate a normalization in database. So what I did I reference `tbl_1` to `tbl_2`. The problem is I don't know how to save each value in an array to a column. example **Classification** has 4 value which I needed to save in `tbl_2` and reference it to `tbl_1`. How am I able to do this? I'm using `PDO`.

HTML snippet:

```
<input type="text" name="classification[]" placeholder="Classification No. 1" />
<input type="text" name="classification[]" placeholder="Classification No. 2" />
<input type="text" name="classification[]" placeholder="Classification No. 3" />
<input type="text" name="classification[]" placeholder="Classification No. 4" />
```

So for each value will create 4 rows that has the same id being reference to `tbl_1`. It should be like this:

[image]

Comment: why dont u used multi dimensional array?... Data[1][1]...etc

Comment: Who is the "Data" array if your page shows a "Classification" array ?
 Moreover, I think you just need to insert first in tbl_1, took the id and then, insert the other values in tbl_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [multidimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead.

So, you `input` can be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="data[classification][]" placeholder="Classification No. 1" />
<input type="text" name="data[area][]" placeholder="Area No. 1" />
<input type="text" name="data[market_value]" placeholder="Market Value No. 1" />
```

Then, using `for` loop, you can `insert` them to `database`:

```
 $data = 'your array here whatever you receive using GET/POST';

for($i=0; $i<count($data['classification']); $i++){
  $sql = INSERT INTO (`tbl_1_id`, `tbl_2_id`, `classification`, `area`, `market_value`) VALUES (`auto_increment_id`, `value_of_table1`, $data['classification'][$i], $data['area'][$i], $data['market_value'][$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving demo....try something like this

```
<?php

$x = 1;
$y = 1;

$classification = array('class1', 'class2');
$area = array('area1', 'area2');
$market = array('market1', 'market2');

$no_of_loop = count($classification); //4

while($no_of_loop)
{
    $query = insert into (`tbl_1_id`, `tbl_2_id`, `Classification`, `Area`, `Market`) values($x, $y, $classification, $area, $market);
$x++;
}
$y++;

mysqli_query($query, $con);

?>
```